# How can I shade my garage door opener keypad?

Tags: doors, garage

My genie garage door opener keypad bakes in the afternoon sun, fades, blisters and delaminates.  Any visually acceptable ideas on a fix? Genie does not offer a weather or sunshield for the KEP-1 keypad

Comment: Can you post a picture?

Comment: "*Any visually acceptable ideas*", this makes this question subjective. There's no way for an answerer to know what is "*visually acceptable*" to you.

Comment: Build a fake birdhouse like structure with a little thatched roof and 4 paned windows w miniature flowerpots on the sides.

Answer (score 1):

An easy *visually pleasing* solution would be to visit your local hardware or electronics store and look for a weather resistant box with a lid similar to the following (2-Gang Rectangle Plastic Electrical Box shown bellow) :

I couldn't find any dimensions but something of this nature will protect the keypad from the elements. It will require you to do some custom fitting ie: removing the keypad, mounting the box, running the ribbon through and then securing the keypad, but will definitely do the job.

[Here is the PDF](https://www.geniecompany.com/data/products/accessories/manuals/wired-keypad_35674R_intructions_eng.pdf) for the model you have provided that should help you with disconnecting / reconnecting the ribbon cable aka Signal Tail.
[image: 2-Gang Rectangle Plastic Electrical Box]
<sub>(source: [imageg.net](http://ace.imageg.net/graphics/product_images/pACE3-15571083enh-z8.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Or go fancy, and build something that looks like a birdbox but has a hinged front face... or maybe even an open face depending on which direction the sunlight is coming from.

Comment: Genie keypad will not fit in that.

Comment: I'd be worried about a greenhouse effect inside the enclosure. While it will keep the sun off, there's a decent chance that it would be hotter inside the enclosure than just being in the sun.

Answer (score 0):

Almost everything will eventually fade if left in direct sun light for years. Outside of cosmetic problems, I'd be concerned about batteries leaking or exploding.

Your best bet might be to relocate the keypad to another location like the other side of the garage.